# Binary formatter producing larger arrays than expected

Tags: c#

Why when using a `BinaryFormatter` to convert an `Int32` to a `byte[]` do I get an array that is not 4 bytes long?

```
static class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bf = new BinaryFormatter();

        using(var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bf.Serialize(ms, 42);

            Console.WriteLine($"{ms.ToArray().Length} bytes");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
54 bytes
```

Comment: The BinaryFormatter adds metadata when serializing - version, culture, and assembly name of the object.

Comment: @stuartd I guess the next question would be: why..?

Comment: @maddisoj because BinaryFormatter also works with `bf.Serialize(ms, yourCustomClass);` too. It needs the extra info to desearalize complex structures.

Comment: binary formatter add type information so the data can be read without knowledge of the content structure.  For a large byte array the memory overhead would be small.  But with random data structures it adds a lot of memory overhead.

Comment: In other words, you're using the wrong tool for the job and complaining that it doesn't do what you want it to do. If you want a binary stream, use `BinaryWriter`. If you want just the `byte[]`, use `BitConverter`. `BinaryFormatter` is designed to serialize and deserialize complex types, not `int`. It's self-describing, so that you can deserialize the contents even when you don't know what's inside.

Comment: @Luaan I didn't know this was the wrong tool, I knew what I wanted to do but being unfarmiliar with the C# library I had to google. Google pointed me to the `BinaryFormatter`. When I tried it out I was really confused why I was getting 54 bytes instead of 4!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BinaryFormatter adds a lot more information when it serializes like the version, culture, and assembly the objects came from.

To just get a 4 byte array you need to use [`BitConverter.GetBytes(42)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4(v=vs.110).aspx), to go back you use [`BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.toint32(v=vs.110).aspx)